# Seeking historic aerials for some areas in Dona Ana County, New Mexico?

Tags: data, united-states, download, aerial-photography

How do I find several historic aerials from the mid-1970's or early 1980's and where can I download them?

I would like them to be free of charge.

[image: Dona Ana County]

[image: Near Anthony, Texas]

[image: Near Hatch, New Mexico]

Comment: You may want to consider posting Questions such as this at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Ok, I post it there.

Answer (score 1):

Not free, but UNM has an archive:

https://edac.unm.edu/image-archive/

Answer (score 0):

You can download lots of historic aerials/imagery from the USGS Earth Explorer website:

https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/